# Select option html in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I'm trying to make the JavaScript for a `<select>`'s `<option>` with 2 items inside it, but I don't seem to be able to do any events once one of them are selected. Here's my code:

```js
var e1 = document.getElementById("#selector").option[0].text;
var e2 = document.getElementById("#selector").option[1].text;
var e3 = document.getElementById("#selector").option[2].text;
document.querySelector("e1").addEventListener("click", myInfo, false);

function myInfo(){
  alert("Test");
}
```

```html
<select id="selector">
  <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select a layout</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is much easier if you use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library.  Is that an option for you?

Comment: Can you tell us what problem you're trying to solve? And, further, `document.querySelector("e1")` is looking for an element `<e1>`, whereas you're probably - or should be - looking to find the `<select>` element, with either `document.getElementById('selector');` or `document.querySelector('#selector')`

Comment: No sorry, It is not at this moment. only html, css and javascript

Comment: @GentlemanMax it's not the question, he's asking for Js solution. Before use Jquery it's better to learn JS before

Comment: @Alexis, that's why it was a comment instead of solution.  I would also tend to disagree with the idea that you need to master JS before jQuery in most situations regardless, though this is hardly the place to discuss it.

Comment: @GentlemanMax, not everything needs jQuery. there is no need to add a massive library to make things "easy" when if you actually learned js, this is easy anyway

Comment: @GentlemanMax Learning js is a must b4 learning jquery

Comment: @Alexis, I'm not saying "don't learn javascript".  I'm saying that mastering JS is not a requirement to use jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your select element looks fine. But your code needs changes:

```
var selector = document.getElementById("selector")

selector.addEventListener("change", function(){
    alert(selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].text);
});
```

This is all you need.
Not to forget to mention that in your code

```
var e3 = document.getElementById("#selector").option[2].text;
```

to select by id just write 'selector' and not '#selector'.
and it is called 'options' not 'option'.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you understand how the functions, especially `querySelector`, work.

You should use change event instead:

```
var val;
document.getElementById("selector").addEventListener("change",function(){
  val = this.value; // or document.getElementById("selector").value
  // then use your value to do other things
});
```

p.s. Please search on the web for the use of the `querySelector` method. Clearly you don't know how it works.